# Controlling active bootstrap tab in angular2 through component based on button click

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using tabs functionality from bootstrap3.3 in angular2. In my template, I have tabs as below:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="tab1">Tab1 Heading</a><li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="tab2">Tab2 Heading</a><li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active in">
      <h3>content for tab1</h3>
    </div>
    </div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>content for tab2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchtab()"> Tab selection</button>
```

In component, I have tried to access using couple of different ways

1. using @viewchild

   ```
   export class myComponent implements OnInit{
     @ViewChild('tab2') tab2: TabsetComponent; //I tried with ElementRef as well
     public switchtab() {
       console.log(this.tab2);  // Here I am getting "undefined" as output
   }
   ```
2. using document.getElementById

   ```
   public switchtab() {
     console.log(document.getElementById('tab2');
     document.getElementById('tab2').class = "tab-pane active in"; //no error
     document.getElementById('tab1').class = "tab-pane fade"; //no error
   }
   ```

Neither of the method didn't make tab2 as active.
Not sure how to make tab2 active.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
</div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3>content for tab2</h3>
</div>
```

To this

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>content for tab2</h3>
</div>
```

Its undefined because you're not registering it in the view, to do that

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="tab1">Tab1 Heading</a><li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="tab2">Tab2 Heading</a><li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active in">
      <h3>content for tab1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade" #tab2>
      <h3>content for tab2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchtab()"> Tab selection</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the type-o correction. I will try your suggestion about registering in the view and get back.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now.
I have added id='tabhead1' and id='tabhead2' for the li elements in nav-tabs (these are tab headings). tab-content has id values already.
So, it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="tab1head" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="tab1">Tab1 Heading</a><li>
    <li id="tab2head"><a data-toggle="tab" href="tab2">Tab2 Heading</a><li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active in">
      <h3>content for tab1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>content for tab2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="switchtab()"> Tab selection</button>
```

In side the component:

```
switchtab() {
  document.getElementById("tab1head").class="";
  document.getElementById("tab2head").class="active";
  document.getElementById("tab1").class="tab-pane fade";
  document.getElementById("tab2").class="tab-pane active in";
}
```

This works to switch from tab1 to tab2. This can be further enhanced to toggle between tabs.

Comment: Property 'class' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'